# PHP WebHook Telegram Bot - SSL CloudFlare

Tags: php, ssl, cloudflare, telegram, telegram-bot

after several researches on the forum I decided to write to see if you can help me.

I want to create a bot telegram in PHP for educational purposes.
I read its documentation, I created a Flexible SSL certificate on CloudFlare for my domain.

I created my bot by telegram and received the token, and set my webhook with the following code

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot <my token>? url = https: //miodominio.eu/page.php
```

the answer is :

```
{"Ok": true, "result": false, "description": "Webhook was set"}
```

I put this code in my page.php

```
<?php 

function checkJSON($chatID,$update){

  $myFile = "log.txt";
  $updateArray = print_r($update,TRUE);
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
  fwrite($fh, $chatID ."\n\n");
  fwrite($fh, $updateArray."\n\n");
  fclose($fh);
}

function sendMessage()
{
  $message = "I am a baby bot.";
  return $message;
}

define('BOT_TOKEN', '< mio token >');
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/');

// read incoming info and grab the chatID
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);
$chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];


// compose reply
$reply =  sendMessage();

// send reply
$sendto =API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$reply;
file_get_contents($sendto);

checkJSON($chatID,$update);

?>
```

But nothing, if I write to boot I do not receive any answer and the log file is not entered anything.
how can I debug?
Do you have any recommendations??
thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this solves your problem, but I find two problems with your code.

To set a webhook, your PHP string should be:

```
'https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebhook?url='.urlencode('https://miodominio.eu/page.php');
```

To send a message, your PHP string should be:

```
API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".urlencode($reply)
```

For any non-trivial parameters, you should always `urlencode()` them before adding them to the query string.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use This code and replace your API:

```
$content=file_get_contents("php://input");
$content = json_decode($content,TRUE);


 $params = array( 
 'chat_id'   => $content["message"]["chat"]["id"],  
 'action'     => 'typing'   
 );
$api="123";
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$api."/sendChatAction";
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   enter code herecurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
   $result=curl_exec ($ch);
```